# How do I fix conda specification unsatisfiableError for python-notebook?

Tags: conda

```
conda install ipython-notebook
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - ipython-notebook -> ipython 0.13.2 -> python 2.6*
  - python 3.6*
```

I tried commands from [Link 1](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2448) . But couldn't resolve.
This is what that links says for opencv.

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge opencv

  - opencv -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install a package that is only available for Python 2.6 (`ipython-notebook`). If you want a recent version of the Jupyter Notebook, the package is just called `notebook`.

As for `opencv`, that error message means that `opencv` is not available for Python 3.6.